# Multiple ribbon groups for Explorer views

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I have a functioning VSTO add-in for Outlook. It currently has a custom ribbon tab / group that appears in the main Outlook Explorer window in the Mail view. It was designed with the ribbon UI designer, not as XML. The ribbon type is set to "Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer" and the tab is set to "TabMail" with the group position set to AfterOfficeId "GroupMailNew".

I am trying to also make it visible in the Calendar view of the Explorer. From what I have seen when searching, I need to make a completely new tab / group, so I have added a new ribbon file using the designer with ribbon type "Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer" like the old one and set the tab to "TabCalendar" and the group position to AfterOfficeId "GroupCalendarNew".

The new ribbon group appears fine when switching to Calendar view in Outlook Explorer, but now the old ribbon group under Mail view has disappeared! I tried rolling back all changes to the old ribbon in source control, so that I am purely adding the new one. But it is still gone. What is happening? Can I only have a single custom ribbon tab / group of type "Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer"?

Answer (score 1):

The ribbon designer doesn't provide all the features that the Fluent UI has on board. To get this working I'd recommend exporting the existing custom UI to the ribbon XML, see [How to: Export a ribbon from the Ribbon Designer to Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-export-a-ribbon-from-the-ribbon-designer-to-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2019) for more information.

In the ribbon XML you may combine both built-in tabs declarations with a custom  UI. The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) is describes in depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Read more about that in the [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2019) article.

Comment: So you are saying that this is a limitation of the ribbon designer that I can avoid by using ribbon XML? I will try that and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Yes, you can easily implement the required functionality by using the ribbon XML.